# Module export return me a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my Cliente.js that its a model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const cliente = sequelize.define('cliente', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    nombre: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'cliente',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
  return cliente;
};
```

and that is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Cliente = require("./Modelos/cliente")
var app = express();
const db = require("./database/db")

db.sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  console.log(Cliente)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

The line "console.log(Cliente) returns me "[Function]" and not the model.

how can i get the model and not the function?

Comment: Assign a model to `module.exports`, not a function.

Comment: How can i do thata? because a reference to Cliente.js

Comment: execute the function: `console.log(Cliente())`

Comment: I obtain error : "TypeError: Cliente is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

So try changing this line

```js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
```

To

```js
exports.sequ = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
```

Then
Change

```js
const Cliente = require("./Modelos/cliente");
```

And this line to
console.log(Cliente.sequ)

Comment: The result is the same: "[Funtion]". Another idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest rereading how to work with [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#model-definition) and rewrite the codebase.

1. `Cliente.js` - exports the function with has 2 parameters.
2. `console.log(Cliente)` - doesn't pass any parameters. Thus how the magic should happen?
3. `Cliente.js` - `const Sequelize = require('sequelize')` is not used.
4. The models must be defined on the sequelize instance which you are using also connect to DB.

```js
//Cliente.js
const DataTypes = require("sequelize");

const cliente = sequelize => {
    const res = sequelize.define('cliente', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        nombre: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'cliente',
        timestamps: false,
        indexes: [
            {
                name: "PRIMARY",
                unique: true,
                using: "BTREE",
                fields: [
                    { name: "id" },
                ]
            },
        ]
    });
    return res;
};

module.exports = cliente
```

and

```js
// index.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db_name>')

;(async () => {
    await sequelize.authenticate()

    const Cliente = require("./cliente")
    const cliente = Cliente(sequelize)
    console.log(cliente)
})()
```

Comment: I have 25 different models, is there a solution that does not involve changing all 25 models?. And i have the instance of sequelize define in db.js, because a need that instance in diferent index.js.